# Reload bash's .profile without logging out and back in again

Tags: bash

Is it possible to coerce bash to reload the .profile file without logging out and back in again?

Comment: Have you tried to use `/etc/profile.d/` scripts? Create the script there, and open a non-login terminal. That runs each time you launch terminal and persists even after you quit terminal.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

This should work for the current terminal:

```
. ~/.profile
```

`.` is a `bash` builtin and a synonym for `source`, see [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/bash):

> .  *filename* [*arguments*]
>   source *filename* [*arguments*]
>        Read  and  execute  commands  from *filename* in the current shell environment (…).

Comment: It will be effective only in the current terminal.

Comment: @enzotib Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: @Matty: no, to make the changes visible to the whole graphical environment, you can only restart the session

Comment: The only issue with this is if you remove something from path it would not take effect until you restart

Comment: @enzotib Is it effective for all sub processes started from current terminal?

Comment: @BruceSun Yes, for all of them.

Comment: @Aras makes an IMPORTANT POINT that deserves expansion: If something is ***removed*** from `~/.profile`, that change will **not** take effect after `. ~/.profile` reload. For example, add a function to `~/.profile`: `function externalip () { curl http://ipecho.net/plain; echo; }`, then `~/.profile` - IT WORKS. Now remove that function from `~/.profile`, then `. ~/.profile` again. The function is still available - only restarting (log out & in) will remove it.

Comment: @enzotib You could theoretically reprogram your window manager to allow it extract the new environment variables from `~/.profile`, which would allow any newly started programs to use the new environment variables without having to restart your entire X11 session, but because of the UNIX design, running processes, as well as programs started by running processes will still need to be restarted to receive the new environment.

It's probably not worth to implement such a feature for something you only do very rarely (Updating `~/.profile`), though.

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want to start a new shell but execute the script in the current shell, you source it:

```
source script_name.sh
```

`source` = `.`

The Bash `source` built-in is a synonym for the Bourne shell `.` (dot) command.

[courtesy - tldp.org](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_01.html)