# Unable to create custom URI scheme on Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, scheme

I created custom URI scheme handler on RedHat Linux and it was working as expected. When user is redirected to the custom URI for example: `myapp://abcd` the browser opens application launcher popup similar to mailto: *handler*.

It wasn't easy to do the similar steps in Ubuntu, I tried all possible solutions available only bu none of them worked.

Here is what I have done for RedHat which worked perfectly:

1. Add an entry in `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`:

   ```
   [Added Associations]
   x-scheme-handler/myprotocol=myprotocol-handler.desktop
   ```
2. Add myprotocol-handler.desktop in `~/.local/share/applications/myprotocol-handler.desktop`:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Exec=sh -c "$HOME/.my-handler.sh %u"
   Icon=
   StartupNotify=true
   Terminal=false
   Categories=Utility;X-XFCE;X-Xfce-Toplevel;
   MimeType=x-scheme-handler/myprotocol
   Name=My Launcher
   Comment=Launch MyProtocol
   ```
3. Create `~/.my-handler.sh`:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   printf "$code" >> file
   xdg-open https://redirect.site.com
   ```

I have tried the above steps on Ubuntu and it is not working, The scheme handler is only working for `xdg-open` command it doesn't work if I try the same URI on the browser.

I tried the below locations:

```
~/.config/
~/.local/share/applications/
~/.local/share/applications/packages
sudo update-desktop-database
xdg-mime command
```

None of the approach works as expected. Can someone point me to the right direction, my Ubuntu version is `16.04.4`

Comment: Hi, have you found this question: [URL protocol handlers in basic Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514125/url-protocol-handlers-in-basic-ubuntu-desktop)

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! I'm sorry, but I'm not clear on what "all possible solutions available" means in this context. Please review https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I did a lot of search and research last 2 days and decided that I cannot get it done without any experts help. I tried all the solutions provided on various discussions, none of them worked :(

Comment: @pa4080 I have tried this url, my solution above is similar to what is posted on the url. I couldn't get it working on Ubuntu, on red hat it worked like a charm.

Comment: To achieve this in Ubuntu, do we have to change `handlers.json` file under `~/.mozilla/firefox/i00uyhbs.default/handlers.json` ?

Answer (score 5):

> I have tried the above steps on Ubuntu and it is not working

If I had to guess, I would say your
[desktop file might not be executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419610/permission-of-a-desktop-file).

```
$ if test -x ~/.local/share/applications/myprotocol-handler.desktop; then echo 'executable'; else echo 'not executable'; fi
```

You can fix this like so:

```
$ chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/myprotocol-handler.desktop
```

Give that a try first.

Also, there are a few other problems I can see right away:

1. Are you registering the `myapp` scheme or the `myprotocol` scheme?

   You mention both of these, and it's somewhat confusing exactly what URLs you want to open.

   I will assume you want to use the `myprotocol` scheme,
   e.g. `myprotocol://abcd`.
2. The "Exec" entry of your desktop file.

   ```
   Exec=sh -c "$HOME/.my-handler.sh %u"
   ```

   The `$HOME/` is not necessary if `.my-handler.sh` is in your `$PATH`.

   The `sh -c` is not necessary if your script is executable,
   since it has the shebang line at the top.
   This also adds another layer of complexity,
   since any URLs will be expanded by the shell
   before they get to your URL handler script.

   The shebang line lists it as a bash script (`#!/bin/bash`),
   but you are using `sh` to execute it instead.
   I don't see any part of the script where that will make a difference,
   but by default `sh` is `dash`,
   a different shell from `bash`.

   ```
   $ type -a sh
   sh is /bin/sh
   $ file /bin/sh
   /bin/sh: symbolic link to dash
   ```
3. The `.my-handler.sh` script.

   You don't need to make it a hidden file;
   a filename like `my-handler.sh` will be fine.
   Since I doubt that your home directory is in `$PATH`,
   there is no advantage to putting it in your home directory
   other than making the absolute path a little shorter.
   (See more about `$PATH` below.)

   Your shebang will work on Ubuntu:

   ```
   $ type -a bash
   bash is /bin/bash
   ```

   but it's a good habit to use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` for portability.

   You are using an uninitialized variable "$code"
   and appending it to a file called `file`.
   What is the purpose of this?
   Since `file` is a relative path,
   this will depend on the working directory,
   which is probably not what you want.
   (For URLs launched from Firefox,
   this will depend on what directory the browser was launched from,
   which might be the home directory, but could be almost anywhere else, too.)

   Your script never uses `"$1"` or any other arguments.
   This means it is essentially discarding the URL it is passed
   and opening `https://redirect.site.com` instead.

   But maybe this is just a placeholder script and this was intentional?
   If so, I would suggest this test script instead:

   ```
   $ cat .my-handler.sh
   #! /usr/bin/env bash
   URL="$1"
   zenity --info --text "URL: ${URL}\nPWD=${PWD}"
   ```

   so you can see the URL passed and directory it's being run from.

> The scheme handler is only working for `xdg-open` command it doesn't work if I try the same URI on the browser.

If `xdg-open` is working, then it's just a matter of configuring the browser.
Based on your comments, it looks like you are using Firefox,
which handles this under Preferences:

[image: Choose how Firefox handles the files you download from the web or the applications you use while browsing.]

> **Applications**
>
> Choose how Firefox handles the files you download from the web or the
>   applications you use while browsing.

This is stored in `handlers.json`, as you mention.

> I tried the below locations

If `xdg-open` is already working,
this should not be an issue,
but one tricky thing about custom URL handlers
is that there are at least four files the associations might be stored in,
depending on the application / library the application uses:

- `~/.config/mimeapps.list` (the right place to make changes)
- `~/.local/share/application/mimeapps.list` (the [deprecated location](https://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/1.0.1/ar01s02.html))
- `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` (the cache of the deprecated location)
- `~/.local/share/application/defaults.list` (the [older deprecated location](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2014-February/013177.html))

We'll address this issue below.

I've been doing some
[work on custom URL handlers](https://github.com/nbeaver/thunderlink-install-guide)
lately, so I've adapted some of that for this purpose.
Here are some step-by-step instructions that may help you:

1. Check if the protocol is already registered.

   ```
   $ gio mime x-scheme-handler/myprotocol
   No default applications for “x-scheme-handler/myprotocol”
   ```

   In my case, the protocol is not already registered.
2. Test the script directly.

   You may need to make it executable, like this:

   ```
   $ chmod +x ~/.my-handler.sh
   ```

   Then use an example URL:

   ```
   $ ~/.my-handler.sh 'myprotocol://abcd'
   ```

   Fix any problems here before continuing on.
3. Add the script to your `$PATH` so the desktop file can find it.

   This step is optional,
   but it is a good habit to get into.
   Putting scripts into `$PATH`
   means you will not have to include the full absolute path in your desktop file,
   so your desktop file will not need to be changed
   if the path to your script changes.

   I use a `bin` directory like this:

   ```
   $ mkdir ~/bin/
   ```

   and add this to `~/.profile`
   (note [you will need to log out and log in again to see changes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59126/reload-bashs-profile-without-logging-out-and-back-in-again)):

   ```
   PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
   ```

   and finally either copy or symlink the script to `~/bin`:

   ```
   $ ln -s $PWD/.my-handler.sh ~/bin/
   ```

   If you did this properly, you should something similar to this:

   ```
   $ type -a .my-handler.sh
   .my-handler.sh is /home/nathaniel/bin/.my-handler.sh
   ```

   not this:

   ```
   $ type -a .my-handler.sh
   bash: type: .my-handler.sh: not found
   ```
4. Install the desktop file.

   It looks like you have done this already,
   but for future reference you can use the `desktop-file-install`
   command from the `desktop-file-utils` package:

   ```
   $ desktop-file-install --dir=$HOME/.local/share/applications/ myprotocol-handler.desktop
   ```

   These are the most important lines in the desktop file:

   ```
   Exec=.my-handler.sh %u
   MimeType=x-scheme-handler/myprotocol
   ```
5. Make sure the desktop file is executable.

   Do this like so:

   ```
   $ chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/myprotocol-handler.desktop
   ```

   This is [necessary as a security measure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419610/permission-of-a-desktop-file).
6. Register the desktop file with the
   `x-scheme-handler/myprotocol` mimetype.

   ```
   $ gio mime x-scheme-handler/myprotocol myprotocol-handler.desktop
   Set myprotocol-handler.desktop as the default for x-scheme-handler/myprotocol
   ```

   All this really does is change lines in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`
   under the `[Default Applications]` group
   so it says this:

   ```
   x-scheme-handler/myprotocol=myprotocol-handler-desktop
   ```

   Some older applications use `~/.local/share/application/mimeapps.list`,
   but this is [officially deprecated](https://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/1.0.1/ar01s02.html).
   However, the `xdg-mime` command uses this location anyway:

   ```
   $ xdg-mime default myprotocol-handler.desktop x-scheme-handler/myprotocol
   ```

   There is also an [even older deprecated file](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2014-February/013177.html)
   called `defaults.list`
   that is still used by some applications.
   Edit this file with a text editor:

   ```
   $ edit ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
   ```

   and manually add these lines:

   ```
   x-scheme-handler/myprotocol=myprotocol-handler.desktop
   ```

   under the `[Default Applications]` group.
7. Check if it was successfully registered.

   ```
   $ gio mime x-scheme-handler/myprotocol
   Default application for “x-scheme-handler/myprotocol”: myprotocol-handler.desktop
   Registered applications:
           myprotocol-handler.desktop
   Recommended applications:
           myprotocol-handler.desktop
   ```

   Check `xdg-mime` also.

   ```
   $ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/myprotocol
   myprotocol-handler.desktop
   ```
8. Test some URLs from the command line.

   ```
   $ gio open 'myprotocol://abcd'
   ```

   Now test the same URL with `xdg-open`:

   ```
   $ xdg-open 'myprotocol://abcd'
   ```
9. Update the mimeinfo cache.

   Some applications read `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`
   instead of `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.
   So update the cache:

   ```
   $ update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```
10. Test it in the browser with a local HTML file.

    ```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example URL</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <a href="myprotocol://abcd">myprotocol://abcd</a>
      </body>
    </html>
    ```

    The first time you open the link,
    Firefox will prompt you to find the desktop file.

    [image: This link needs to be opened with an application.]

    Navigate to `~/.local/share/applications/` and click `myprotocol-handler.desktop`.

    Also tick the box that says "Remember my choice for myprotocol links."

    [image: myprotocol-handler.desktop]

    It should look like this when you're done.

    [image: Use My Launcher (default)]
11. Test it in the browser with a remote HTML file.

    There are some security differences between local and remote HTML files,
    so it's good to check both.
    You could set up some hosting for this,
    or just use Github or similar, but that's outside the scope of this question.