# How can I configure a domain-specific default browser?

Tags: default-programs

If the url matches `.*\.myemployer\.com.*` then I want the link to open in chromium.  Otherwise I want it to open in brave.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: I don't think this is easily achievable, system-wide. An alternative could be, to install a plugin in brave, to open specific links/domains in another browser. I do have a setup like this for firefox.

Comment: @RobertRiedl Thanks for your comment.  I hadn't thought of using the browser itself to handle this, that's a clever solution. --  Still.. there's gotta be some component that handles the link-click event and starts the appropriate browser--I realize it would likely be a code change to that component, but I'm kind of interested in getting my hands dirty with this one.

Comment: Well, then there is this answer [here over at superuser](https://superuser.com/a/688094/395620) !

Comment: Oh that's clever, just intercept it by placing your own xdg-open earlier in the PATH...  The connection you've made is exactly what I was looking for.  If you write up a quick answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/514125/url-protocol-handlers-in-basic-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrService What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55214/how-to-override-the-gnome-3-ssh-handler

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that there is a difference between the `text/html` mimetype
(this is opening actual HTML files)
and the `x-scheme-handler/http` mimetype
(this is an HTTP URL).
I assume you want to customize how external applications open HTTP/HTTPS URLs,
since you mention domains.
(Note that this is for external applications.
Customizing how a particular *browser* handles an HTTP URL
is a different thing altogether.)

One tricky thing about custom URL handlers
is that there are at least four files the associations might be stored in,
depending on the application / library the application uses:

- `~/.config/mimeapps.list` (the right place to make changes)
- `~/.local/share/application/mimeapps.list` (the [deprecated location](https://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/1.0.1/ar01s02.html))
- `~/.local/share/application/defaults.list` (the older [deprecated location](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2014-February/013177.html))
- `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` (the cache)

I've been doing some [work on custom URL handlers](https://github.com/nbeaver/thunderlink-install-guide)
lately, so I've adapted some of that for this purpose.
Here are the instructions:

1. Check the currently registered file for the protocols.
   Here's what they look like for me:

   ```
   $ gio mime x-scheme-handler/http
   Default application for “x-scheme-handler/http”: firefox.desktop
   Registered applications:
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   Recommended applications:
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   $ gio mime x-scheme-handler/https
   Default application for “x-scheme-handler/https”: firefox.desktop
   Registered applications:
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   Recommended applications:
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   ```
2. Write a [script that parses the URL and launches the appropriate browser](https://github.com/nbeaver/askubuntu-custom-http-url-handler/blob/2df6569ef641120d69b4d14aa40086be9d93dd7a/http_url_handler.py).

   I prefer to use Python,
   since it has libraries to parse URLs and send errors to syslog.

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/env python3

   import subprocess
   import logging
   import argparse
   import syslog
   import sys

   try :
       from urllib.parse import urlparse
   except ImportError:
       from urlparse import urlparse
   import os.path

   def http_url(url):
       if url.startswith('http://'):
           return url
       if url.startswith('https://'):
           return url
       else:
           syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, sys.argv[0] + ": not an HTTP/HTTPS URL: '{}'".format(url))
           raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(
               "not an HTTP/HTTPS URL: '{}'".format(url))

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
           description='Handler for http/https URLs.'
       )
       parser.add_argument(
           '-v',
           '--verbose',
           help='More verbose logging',
           dest="loglevel",
           default=logging.WARNING,
           action="store_const",
           const=logging.INFO,
       )
       parser.add_argument(
           '-d',
           '--debug',
           help='Enable debugging logs',
           action="store_const",
           dest="loglevel",
           const=logging.DEBUG,
       )
       parser.add_argument(
           'url',
           type=http_url,
           help="URL starting with 'http://' or 'https://'",
       )
       args = parser.parse_args()
       logging.basicConfig(level=args.loglevel)
       logging.debug("args.url = '{}'".format(args.url))
       parsed = urlparse(args.url)
       if parsed.hostname == 'askubuntu.com':
           browser = 'firefox'
       else:
           browser = 'chromium-browser'
       logging.info("browser = '{}'".format(browser))
       cmd = [browser, args.url]
       try :
           status = subprocess.check_call(cmd)
       except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
           syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, sys.argv[0] + "could not open URL with browser '{}': {}".format(browser, args.url))
           raise
   ```

   Adapt the script to your liking,
   particularly the executable for `brave` (I haven't used it, so I don't know)
   and the hostname in the `if parsed.hostname` part.
3. Test the script from the current directory.

   This should open with Firefox:

   ```
   $ ./http_url_handler.py 'https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161752/how-can-i-configure-a-domain-specific-default-browser'
   ```

   This should open with Chromium:

   ```
   $ ./http_url_handler.py 'https://superuser.com/questions/688063/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-certain-urls-to-specific-web-browsers-in-linux/'
   ```
4. Add the script to your `$PATH` so the desktop file can find it.

   I use a `bin` directory like this:

   ```
   $ mkdir ~/bin/
   ```

   and add this to `~/.profile`
   (note [you will need to log out and log in again to see changes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59126/reload-bashs-profile-without-logging-out-and-back-in-again)):

   ```
   PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
   ```

   and finally either copy or symlink the script to `~/bin`:

   ```
   $ ln -s $PWD/http_url_handler.py ~/bin/
   ```

   If you did this properly, you should see this:

   ```
   $ type -a http_url_handler.py 
   http_url_handler.py is /home/nathaniel/bin/http_url_handler.py
   ```

   not this:

   ```
   $ type -a http_url_handler.py 
   bash: type: http_url_handler.py: not found
   ```
5. Test the script from your home directory.

   This should open in Chromium:

   ```
   $ http_url_handler.py 'https://superuser.com/questions/688063/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-certain-urls-to-specific-web-browsers-in-linux'
   ```

   This should open in Firefox:

   ```
   $ http_url_handler.py 'https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161752/how-can-i-configure-a-domain-specific-default-browser'
   ```
6. Install the desktop file. Here's the [one I used](https://github.com/nbeaver/askubuntu-custom-http-url-handler/blob/2df6569ef641120d69b4d14aa40086be9d93dd7a/http-url-handler.desktop):

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=HTTP URL handler
   Comment=Open an HTTP/HTTPS URL with a particular browser
   TryExec=http_url_handler.py
   Exec=http_url_handler.py %u
   X-MultipleArgs=false
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   NoDisplay=true
   MimeType=x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https
   ```

   Either via `desktop-file-install`:

   ```
   $ desktop-file-install --dir=$HOME/.local/share/applications/ http-url-handler.desktop
   ```

   or manually copy the `http-url-handler.desktop` file
   to the proper directory,
   which should be `~/.local/share/applications/`:

   ```
   $ cp http-url-handler.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
   ```

   These are the most important lines in the desktop file:

   ```
   Exec=http_url_handler.py %u
   MimeType=x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https
   ```
7. Make the desktop file executable.

   ```
   $ chmod +x $HOME/.local/share/applications/http-url-handler.desktop
   ```

   This is [necessary because of a security precaution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419610/permission-of-a-desktop-file).
8. Register the desktop file with the
   `x-scheme-handler/http` and `x-scheme-handler/https` mimetypes.

   ```
   $ gio mime x-scheme-handler/http  http-url-handler.desktop
   Set http-url-handler.desktop as the default for x-scheme-handler/http
   $ gio mime x-scheme-handler/https http-url-handler.desktop
   Set http-url-handler.desktop as the default for x-scheme-handler/https
   ```

   All this really does is change lines in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`
   under the `[Default Applications]` group
   so that instead of this:

   ```
   x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop
   x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop
   ```

   it says this:

   ```
   x-scheme-handler/http=http-url-handler.desktop
   x-scheme-handler/https=http-url-handler.desktop
   ```

   You can also add it under the `[Added Associations]` group
   with a text editor so it looks something like this:

   ```
   x-scheme-handler/http=http-url-handler.desktop;firefox.desktop;chromium-browser.desktop
   x-scheme-handler/https=http-url-handler.desktop;firefox.desktop;chromium-browser.desktop
   ```

   Some older applications use `~/.local/share/application/mimeapps.list`,
   but this is [officially deprecated](https://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/1.0.1/ar01s02.html).
   However, the `xdg-mime` command uses this location anyway:

   ```
   $ xdg-mime default http-url-handler.desktop x-scheme-handler/http
   $ xdg-mime default http-url-handler.desktop x-scheme-handler/https
   ```

   There is also an [even older deprecated file](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2014-February/013177.html)
   called `defaults.list`
   that is still used by some applications.
   Edit this file with a text editor:

   ```
   $ edit ~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list
   ```

   and manually add these lines:

   ```
   x-scheme-handler/http=http-url-handler.desktop
   x-scheme-handler/https=http-url-handler.desktop
   ```

   under the `[Default Applications]` group.
9. Check if it was successfully registered.

   ```
   $ gio mime x-scheme-handler/http
   Default application for “x-scheme-handler/http”: http-url-handler.desktop
   Registered applications:
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   Recommended applications:
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   $ gio mime x-scheme-handler/https
   Default application for “x-scheme-handler/https”: http-url-handler.desktop
   Registered applications:
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   Recommended applications:
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   ```

   If you also added to the `[Added Associations]` group,
   it will look like something like this:

   ```
   $ gio mime x-scheme-handler/http
   Default application for “x-scheme-handler/http”: http-url-handler.desktop
   Registered applications:
           http-url-handler.desktop
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   Recommended applications:
           http-url-handler.desktop
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   $ gio mime x-scheme-handler/https
   Default application for “x-scheme-handler/https”: http-url-handler.desktop
   Registered applications:
           http-url-handler.desktop
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   Recommended applications:
           http-url-handler.desktop
           firefox.desktop
           chromium-browser.desktop
   ```

   Check `xdg-mime` also.

   ```
   $ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
   http-url-handler.desktop
   $ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
   http-url-handler.desktop
   ```
10. Test some URLs.

    This should open in Chromium:

    ```
    $ gio open 'https://superuser.com/questions/688063/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-certain-urls-to-specific-web-browsers-in-linux'
    ```

    This should open in Firefox:

    ```
    $ gio open 'https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161752/how-can-i-configure-a-domain-specific-default-browser'
    ```

    Now test the same URLs with `xdg-open`:

    ```
    $ xdg-open 'https://superuser.com/questions/688063/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-certain-urls-to-specific-web-browsers-in-linux/'

    $ xdg-open 'https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161752/how-can-i-configure-a-domain-specific-default-browser'
    ```
11. Update the mimeinfo cache.

    Some applications read `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`
    instead of `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.
    So update the cache:

    ```
    $ update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/
    ```

For convenience, the files are on Github here:

https://github.com/nbeaver/askubuntu-custom-http-url-handler

Comment: Used the above to make my own heavily customizable version: https://github.com/JonTheNiceGuy/usbrowser - put /etc/usbrowser_config.yml or ~/.usbrowser_config.yml to have your own paths. The only thing I've not figured out how to do, is to register it as the default browser handler!

Answer (score 3):

What you want is very easy, you are just approaching it from the wrong angle.

Create a script (just change mozilla and chrome to full paths of google-chrome and brave.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Reading argument values using loop
isFound=0;
for argval in "$@"
do
  #echo -n "$argval  "
  if [[ $argval == *myemployer* ]]; then
    isFound=1;
    break;
  fi
done


if [[ isFound -eq 1 ]]; then
    mozilla $@;
else
    chrome $@;
fi
```

and save this shell script (with the changes as selectBrowser.sh

Next, in this shell script as the default browser.

Done.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of poking around, I think the component I'm looking for is part of Gnome.  There appears to be a correspondence between mime types and apps:

```
❯ gio mime text/html
Default application for “text/html”: chromium-browser.desktop
Registered applications:
    firefox.desktop
    chromium-browser.desktop
    brave-browser.desktop
    vim.desktop
    nvim.desktop
    org.gnome.gedit.desktop
Recommended applications:
    firefox.desktop
    chromium-browser.desktop
    brave-browser.desktop
```

There's also some info here: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/mime-types-application.html.en

Following a good idea from @RobertRiedl, I may register a "browser" on the text/html mimetype which is actually just a small program that will check the string and then launch the desired program.  I figure you could use this to drive other mimetype remappings too.

If I get this working I'll update this answer with details.

Comment: I like this approach ! Let see how it turns out.