How can I open Youtube urls via an xdg entry with Freetube?
I want to open Youtube urls from various browsers and applications like Twitter directly with Freetube. Is this possible via xdg?
I tried it optionally with the Firefox app “External Application Button” and “openbydomain-master”, but it doesn't work.
When I enter the Freetube command in the terminal, followed by the YT url, Freetube opens and plays the video.

I was able to solve it with this script:
#!/bin/bash
# Reading argument values using loop
isFound=0;
for argval in "$@"
do
#echo -n "$argval  "
if [[ $argval == *youtu* ]]; then
isFound=1;
break;
fi
done


if [[ isFound -eq 1 ]]; then
/opt/FreeTube/freetube %U $@;
else
/home/user/Downloads/openbydomain-master/openbydomain.py $@;
fi

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1164060/1648218
Via openbydomain.py alone, all http(s) links are opened with the set default internet browser, also the YT links, although the path to Freetube is entered.
openbydomain-csv
